# How to add sound effects in Ubuntu

Tags: sound

I just was wondering how you can add sound affects i.e. start up sound effect, minimize windows etc. to ubuntu 14.10.
I know this is possible in KDE, but how to go about doing this in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

There are certain sounds built in. Open the DConf Editor (Alt+F2 and then type `dconf-editor`) and navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.sound`. Make sure to select both the checkboxes. Make sure the sound scheme name is "`ubuntu`" if you just want the default sounds.

To install DConf editor if you haven't installed it already, find it on Synaptic or do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install dconf-editor` in the terminal.

[DConf Editor on org.gnome.desktop.sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPff8.png)

Comment: How do I add my own custom sounds?